# jQuery component to Vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a situation to convert several **jQuery components** to **VueJs**.

In general, I know what to do, but in some cases, I need to replace some functions calls.

For instance:

**Component**

```js
const Component = (function () {
  const initialize = () => {
    return 'Tony Stark'
  }   
  return {
    initialize: initialize
  }
})

export default Component
```

**Random file, using exported function**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Component.initialize()
});
```

What is the best solution to **Component.initialize()** still working? 
Because I have this request in several files.

Answer (score 0):

You may `import` the component to every Vue component and use it like this:

```
import someComponent from './someComponent'
export default {
  created () {
    Component.initialize()
  }
}
```

Or you could use instance properties, see https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html

Comment: My task is to kill this: Component.initialize() ... and only to use Vue.

Comment: You should move jQuery component logic to Vue then.

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution:

```js
import Component from './component'

// Call method
Component.methods.method()
```